# Any C# library to do webrequest similar to httpwebrequest but not throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, httpwebrequest

I 'm looking for a similar library or class like httpwebrequest which does not throw exceptions on http codes. (c# language)
Problem with httpwebrequest is that it behaves the http error codes (like 401,403 and ...) as exceptions and throws an exception in case of these. You may know that exception throwing and handling is expensive. for example a successful request takes about 30 ms on my system,but another request which causes exception takes about 250!
I 'm making lots of request that causes this http error codes and it affects my code performance alot.
I have tried webclient,webrequest,httpclient and all are the same in this.

Any opinion on a alternative library or how to avoid these exceptions ?

Comment: http://restsharp.org/ maybe?

Comment: I think `HttpClient` doesn't throw exceptions. It's the newer implementation anyway. But I don't think that the exceptions are the such an expensive part of an web request  to care about them.

Comment: This is sort of my personal issue with exceptions, if you have code that is throwing that many exceptions, as frequently as you are saying, *the better solution is to re-work your data to not throw so many exceptions, not ignore the exceptions or handle them*, because for every exception you handle, you are slowing performance down by that much, when you could have just re-worked your system to not throw the exceptions in the first place.

Comment: My code is checking just for existence of lots of urls. I can't prevent them because they are thrown by http codes 404 (not found) by httpwebrequest! @TrevorHart

Comment: HttpClient thrrows exception too and exceptions are so expensive. compare 3ms against 40ms! @Dr.Fre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpClient.GetAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944(v=vs.110).aspx) won't throw an exception on a 400-level error. Though it will throw an exception for "an underlying issue such as network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout."

Also, the HttpReponseMessage it produces has a handy [IsSuccessStatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `RestSharp`. It's a great tool for creating web requests